# Transposing datasets with multiple rows in a file into a single row per dataset

Tags: python

Could I please have some pointers to websites where I can read and get the skills to write python code to do the following?

So far I can only find python code that reads structured data into lists and dictionaries. I need to see an example with line processing to merge multiple rows of data to a single row.

**Problem**

I have datasets in a file, each dataset is enclosed in `{}`, with one item per row.

I need to transpose all the items of a data set to a single row ie transpose to tabular> Below is an example

**Input file:**

```
details_book1{
title,txt, book_book1

author,txt,author_book1

price,txt, price_book1 }



details_book2

{

title,txt, book_book2

author,txt,author_book2

price,txt, price_book2 
}
```

**Output Required:**

```
details_book1,book_book1,author_book1,price_book1
details_book2,book_book2,author_book2,price_book2
...
details_bookn,book_bookn,author_bookn,price_bookn
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't know of particular references, other than just learning about string and list manipulations, for which the python docs aren't too bad, but it could perhaps be as simple as something like this:

```
lines = [line for line in a.split('\n') if line]

books = []
book = ''
for line in lines:
    if '}' in line:
        book += ',' + line
        book = book.replace('{', ' ').replace('}', ' ')
        books.append([x.strip() for x in book.split(',') if x.strip()])
        book = ''
    else:
        book += line + ','
```

This would create a list of lists of the entitites, and you could loop through the list, pulling out all the elements into variables:

```
for book, title, a, bookbook, author, b, authorbook, price, c, pricebook in books:
    print '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (book, bookbook, authorbook, pricebook)

# result
details_book1,book_book1,author_book1,price_book1
details_book2,book_book2,author_book2,price_book2
```

This can fail in a few ways, though, and requires that your data match what you've shown so far. In particular, if you have commas in any of the the text, where I split the book variable around commas inside the second list comprehension will split into too many fields, and the unpacking later in the for loop (last example code snippet) will fail.

Also, if a block starts on the same line as the previous block's }, it will fail to cut up the data correctly. There are ways around this, but I wanted to keep things very simple.

Maybe this can help as a starting point.

I suppose you could do this as well:

```
import re
for book in re.findall('\w.*?{.*?}', a, flags=re.M|re.S):
    book = book.replace('\n',',').replace('{',',').replace('}',',')
    book = [x.strip() for x in book.split(',') if x.strip()]
    print book
```

This uses a regular expression via the re.findall to find all words followed by any amount of whitespace, and anything at all (non-greedy) between curly braces. This results in a bit of a mess of newlines and missing commas, so then I replace newlines and braces with commas, then use a list comprehension to split around commas, strip whitespace around each split element, and leave out any empty strings that result.

This results in these lists each time in book:

```
['details_book1', 'title', 'txt', 'book_book1', 'author', 'txt', 'author_book1', 'price', 'txt', 'price_book1']
['details_book2', 'title', 'txt', 'book_book2', 'author', 'txt', 'author_book2', 'price', 'txt', 'price_book2']
```

Again, splitting around commas is a problem if anything like book titles or txt blurbs have commas in them (but if they do, I don't know how you're able to tell those blurbs apart from the comma-separated bits on each line).